# How can I add a UIGestureRecognizer to a UITableViewCell subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

imgView is a UIImageView that is added as a subview to a custom UITableViewCell class.  The action isn't being called when the image is tapped.

```
[imgView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openMedia:)]];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UIImageView ignores user events by default.  You need to enable them with:

```
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Beware, you are also leaking your gesture recognizer.

Comment: :P  That was an easy mistake.  Thanks for the tip on the leak... forgot to autorelease it